# Automate settings panes with iPad Pro

Tags: c#, appium

I'm trying to automate scrolling through the 'Settings' app on iOS, it works on iPhones, however on the iPad the 'Settings' app has two panes and whenever I scroll it affects the right pane. I'd want the scrolling to occur on the left pane.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I've tried to click on an item on the left, which works however upon scrolling the focus is still on the right pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll or swipe or even build your own TouchAction sequence based on an element in the left pane. I'm assuming your current code is not scrolling based on a target.

Comment: Yeah the answer was to use the element to scroll rather than swipe, which I was doing. I guess I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: Code is below in my own answer for anyone loooking

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else:

```
            var scroll = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            scroll.Add("direction", "down");
            scroll.Add("name", name);`
            driver.ExecuteScript("mobile:scroll", scroll);
```

where `name` was the name attr of that element